# The "error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value." caused by "strict": false in tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, typescript

At first, I'd like to reproduce my issue.

1. Create a new Angular project

   ```bash
   ng new ng-ts-strict-issue
   cd ng-ts-strict-issue
   ```
2. Modify `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`. Let's set `strict` to `false`.

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "strict": false,
       ...
     },
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Add a method to the `app.component.ts`.

   ```
   test(p: string): string | null | undefined {
     if (p === 'test') {
       return;
     }
     return null;
   }
   ```
4. Run `ng build`

   ```
   ⠼ Building...✘ [ERROR] TS7030: Not all code paths return a value. [plugin angular-compiler]

       src/app/app.component.ts:17:6:
         17 │       return;
           ╵       ~~~~~~


   Application bundle generation failed. [3.905 seconds]
   ```

   [image: TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.]

Actually, I know this error. The error is related to [`"noImplicitReturns": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns) setting in the `tsconfig.json` file. I actually can turn this option off to avoid this issue.

But my question is why the `return;` statement will lead to `TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.` error only when [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) been set to `false`? I actually already returned on every path. Why I violated the `noImplicitReturns` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictnullchecks) is disabled, your code is interpreted as:

```
function test(p: string): string {
  if (p === 'test') {
    return; // error
  }
  return null;
}
```

That is, `string | null | undefined` is just `string` because `null` and `undefined` are implicitly contained in every type.  According to [microsoft/TypeScript#7358](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7358), the bare `return` statement is therefore considered likely to be a mistake because it does not return a `string`, nor does it explicitly return `null` or `undefined`.  This behavior was requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#5916](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5916).

The error message might not be the best, since it *looks* like it's saying "not all code paths return" but it really means "not all code paths *explicitly* return *a value*".

Anyway, the fix here (assuming you want to keep your compiler options as-is) would be to explicitly return `undefined` instead:

```
function test(p: string): string {
  if (p === 'test') {
    return undefined; // okay
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgA4C5EYBOMYA5gJT5EmmIDeAUIojMIjogLzeIDkqGXuXpNmiQiighCYANyiAvqIlSZiMCAA2m+UoahIsBMnRQATDipRiZSgWs0RzVu2xce-U0KdiV0pOAAJijAJCiB8sxKzH5qGtq6QA)